# Three Phase Power (Delta Source connected to Delta Load)

Tags: power, current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIKrBo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will the magnitude of the current through the delta sources always be equal to the magnitude of the current though the delta loads?   I have searched online, read the textbook but cannot get a definitive answer.  The circuit displayed is more for visually purposes only.  I do not want to know the values.  The loads are the capacitors (which could be anything as long as the same) and the sources are the sources.

Comment: Be unambiguous, draw a picture and point to which currents you are comparing?

Comment: A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Sorry about that I cleaned it up a little bit.  Hopefully I cleared it up.